# Common Lisp CFFI and C exit codes

Tags: common-lisp, exit-code, cffi

I have successfully coupled a C library with Common Lisp, with the help of CFFI. However, the C library uses exit codes to catch errors, which leads to an abrupt termination of the lisp program. It seems there is a library called trivial-signal that handles signals in UNIX systems. Does it work also on Windows? Or maybe is there another way to handle the termination of the program?

What I have thought is to replace the exit codes with a callback to a lisp function, which will throw an exception. Will this approach work?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What library is it?

Comment: An in-house legacy one. Actually a stand-alone command line program, which I convert to library and bind to common lisp.

Answer (score 4):

There's no straightforward way to intercept and cancel `exit()` calls. Even if you could, the code that called `exit()` does not expect execution to continue past that call, and may not have bothered deallocating memory or otherwise cleaning up after itself. Signals are generally thrown to instruct a process to exit, not by the process itself.

If you can't change the library, your only practical option is to run the library from a child process, such that the library exiting doesn't cause your main application to exit (and so that the main application can read the exit code).

EDIT: Based on your comment, I'd suggest sticking with the standalone program and calling that, rather than calling a library-ized version (since you'll have to have a second process in any case).

Comment: Hmm, I don't like this approach, because I have to extend the functionality. Maybe if I substitute the exit calls, with setting the error code in a global variable and returning something (because most functions of the library return something). Then in the lisp function I would read the global variable and do the error handling inside it.

Comment: @Dimitris You could call the Lisp callback as you said earlier, but keep in mind Sneftel's remark about the original code calling "exit" without properly deallocating memory, etc.

Comment: ok, so which lisp library do you propose to use in order to handle this situation?