# Common Lisp CFFI setjmp/longjmp

Tags: common-lisp, setjmp, cffi

I am calling functions in the [MuPDF C library](https://mupdf.com/) using Common Lisp and CFFI. [MuPDF uses setjmp/longjmp for exception handling](https://mupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/C-API-core.html#error-handling). The MuPDF website states:

> All functions you call should be guarded by a fz_try block to catch
> the errors, or the program will call exit() on errors. You don’t want
> that.

Even though I have yet to encounter an exception when calling MuPDF, it would be nice to handle any future exceptions in a graceful manner.

Based on my understanding of setjmp/longjmp, I think the answer to the following question is "no" (but hopefully I'm wrong). Is it possible to use Common Lisp and CFFI to hook into MuPDF's exception handling system?

If it is not possible, then this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48238880/common-lisp-cffi-and-c-exit-codes) seems applicable.

Comment: `setjmp` and `longjmp` are legacy disasters that are best forgotten.  They are akin to using a chainsaw to remove a splinter.  They do not play well with any object-oriented language.  I do not like your chances of success.

Comment: There are bindings to C++ and Python so I guess this is worth reading: https://mupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/language-bindings.html I was also looking for the source code to understand how the block is implemented: https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/mupdf/blob/9a35f1652ed34ea6aaa7daef36de219b1ed8a3ce/include/mupdf/fitz/context.h#L56

Comment: By the way, this very thing is on my TODO list in the TXR Lisp FFI.   It's not easy because FFI calls have to do their own resource management for temporary objects; if we let a longjmp out of a FFI call, that stuff will leak. So it has to be integrated, most likely: a special kind of FFI call that expects a longjmp and handles it together with regular return.

Comment: There is at least one other famous library which does this. I think libjpeg? No, libpng, that's it.  *"When libpng encounters an error, it expects to longjmp back to your routine. Therefore, you will need to call setjmp and pass your png_jmpbuf(png_ptr)"* Party time!

Comment: If I get around to it, I will probably introduce a built-in FFI type called `jmp-buf`. Then I will have it so that whenever this appears as an argument in a `deffi` function, in any position, it will define a function that is handled specially. The call will itself allocate a `jmp_buf` and call `setjmp`, and that buffer will be passed in that argument position (which will be removed from the Lisp-facing function). If the function returns via longjmp, everything will still be handled right.

Comment: What we almost certainly don't want is to expose a setjmp primitive that the Lisp code has to use around the FFI call.